# Equal group randomization in groups already assigned treatment

Tags: r, dataframe, random, sample

I have a list of 80 subjects already randomized into 4 groups (1-4). Now, I want to introduce a crossover design so each subject will eventually be in all 4 groups. Tried to do this with the sample function, but I need an equal distribution of each possibility of the 3 remaining groups to be randomized.

For example:
Subject A was already randomized to group 1. Now I need to randomize the remaining 3 groups (2, 3, 4)
There are 6 options to randomize the 3 remaining groups:
234
243
324
342
423
432

So I need to ensure that every subject who was initially assigned to group 1 (20 subjects) gets an even distribution of one of those 6 permutations above. The same for every subject initially assigned to group 2, 3 and 4

I tried

```
#for loop going through each row of the dataframe
for(x in 1:nrow(crossover)) {
  #TRIAL 2
  #randomly selects an integer between 1 and 4

 y<- sample(1:4, 1, replace = TRUE)
  
  #if it equals Assigned.Arm.Index, then randomly select again
 while (y == crossover$Assigned.Arm.Index[x]){

    y <- sample(1:4, 1, replace = FALSE)
  }
  
  #set New.Arm.Index column to y
  crossover$Trial_2[x] <- y
```

crossover is the name of my dataframe, assigned.arm.index is the premade initial randomization. I created 3 new columns for the remaining randomization I'm trying to fill.

When i asked for help regarding equal randomization across all subjects, I was told to use the rep function, something like:

```
sample(rep(1:6, 4) , rep= FALSE)
```

but it's not fully making sense to me. Im new to R and appreciate any help!

Comment: so given the 1st randomization, you need to randomize each patient 3 more times such that the groups are not repeated? `r1 <- sample(1:4, 80, TRUE); data.frame(r1, t(sapply(r1, function(x) sample((1:4)[-x]))))`

Comment: Yes! I need to randomize each patient so that each group is not repeated

Comment: that won't guarantee you have 20/20/20/20 in each randomization which is trickier. if your initial randomization is balanced, you could order the initial data set such that IDs are assigned to 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., and then just shift those assignments by 1 three times, ie, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, ...

Comment: I believe we dont need 20/20/20/20 in each randomization anymore, we just need to ensure the randomization of the remaining 3 groups for each initial assigned treatment is balanced (equal or close enough balance of the 6 possible permutations).

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, essentially what you are wanting is a series of random Latin squares, enough so that every subject has a row of 4 distinct treatments. The `rlatin()` function from the `magic` package is perfect for what you want.

As you have randomised your subjects into 4 groups once already, we are going to use that column as a basis to join each subject's remaining treatment values. In the example below, "treatment1" is the column with your already randomised group values.

The workflow is as follows:

1. Create a "ranjoin" column in df, and add a unique random value between 1 and 20 based on your "treatment1" groups. In other words, each subject in each group is assigned a random value. "ranjoin" will be used with "treatment1" to join remaining treatment groups to
2. Create an 80 x 4 dataframe (df1) of random 4 x 4 Latin squares, the first column corresponding to "treatment1" in df
3. As you did for df, assign a random "ranjoin" value to the df1 "treatment1" groups
4. Use the "treatment1" and "ranjoin" columns in df and df1 to complete sampled treatment groups for each subject

Let's take group 1 as an example. There are 20 subjects in df who have a "treatment1" value of 1 and a random unique "ranjoin" value of 1:20. There are also 20 "treatment1" values of 1 in df1, again with a random unique "ranjoin" value of 1:20. If "subject" 1 has a "treatment1" value of 1 and a "ranjoin" value of 7, the corresponding row from df1 is joined to the row of subject "1". The key to this approach is that the "ranjoin" columns are independently randomised. I kept `set.seed(1)` the same for this whole example for replicability. Insert different `set.seed()` values where indicated in the codeblock below to ensure more randomised results.

```
library(magic)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Example of your existing df where "treatment1" contains your existing group sampling
# and subvar columns are just 'dummy' subject data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(subject = 1:80,
                 treatment1 = rep(sample(1:4, 4, replace = FALSE), 20),
                 subvar1 = round(rnorm(80, 0, 10), 2),
                 subvar2 = round(rnorm(80, 0, 10), 2),
                 subvar3 = round(rnorm(80, 0, 10), 2)) 


# Assign random value between 1:n() so each treatment group has a random 'rank'
# set.seed(sample(1e+08:1e+09, 1)) # Use something like this before running

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(treatment1) %>%
  mutate(ranjoin = sample(1:n(), n(), replace = FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup()

head(data.frame(df))
  subject treatment1 subvar1 subvar2 subvar3 ranjoin
1       1          1   12.72   -2.20   16.80      20
2       2          3    4.15   -4.25    7.80       8
3       3          4  -15.40   -4.19    7.13       5
4       4          2   -9.29    9.97   -5.43      15
5       5          1   -2.95   -2.76    8.86       9
6       6          3   -0.06   12.56   -3.49       2

# Create 4 x 80 random treatments and join to df 
# set.seed(sample(1e+08:1e+09, 1)) # Use something like this again before running

df1 <- data.frame(rlatin(20, 4)) %>% # Create dataframe of 20 random 4 x 4 Latin squares
  mutate(names = paste0("treatment", 1:4)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-names) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = names,
              values_from = value) %>%
  group_by(treatment1) %>%
  mutate(ranjoin = sample(1:n(), n(), replace = FALSE)) %>% # Same as for df
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(df, by = c("treatment1", "ranjoin"), keep = FALSE) %>%
  select(-c(name, ranjoin)) %>%
  relocate(subject) %>%
  arrange(subject)
  
head(data.frame(df1))
  subject treatment1 treatment2 treatment3 treatment4 subvar1 subvar2 subvar3
1       1          1          4          2          3   12.72   -2.20   16.80
2       2          3          4          1          2    4.15   -4.25    7.80
3       3          4          1          2          3  -15.40   -4.19    7.13
4       4          2          3          4          1   -9.29    9.97   -5.43
5       5          1          3          4          2   -2.95   -2.76    8.86
6       6          3          4          1          2   -0.06   12.56   -3.49

# Check treatment group sizes are equal per "treatment" column
table(stack(df1[,2:5]))
      ind
values treatment1 treatment2 treatment3 treatment4
     1         20         20         20         20
     2         20         20         20         20
     3         20         20         20         20
     4         20         20         20         20

# Check each subject has been assigned 4 different treatment values, 0 == TRUE
sum(apply(df1[,2:5], 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) < 4)
0
```